# closed sets which are strictly contained in open set

Tags: general-topology

I wanted to ask the following:
Suppose I am in the complex plane with the usual topology.
Suppose I have a closed set **A** such that **A** ⊂ **B**, where **B** is an open set. I wanted to know if I can always find a closed set **A'** such that **A** ⊂ **A'** ⊂ **B**?
But with one more demand - That the smallest distance between boundaries of **A** and **A'** will be strictly positive. You can visualize my question as: is it possible to "inflate" **A** a bit so it could still be totally contained in **B**?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not if A intersects BdryB.

Comment: @gary I did not understand

Comment: :Never mind, I missed the fact that $A \subset B$ . I think the generl topic here is that of separation axioms, i.e., the T_ axioms.

Comment: Well we have here a very convenient metric space

Comment: I think it may be possible if A is also compact, avoiding the situation in pllosu2's answer below.

Comment: Yes A is compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A compact, then the continuous function $d(A,B)$  takes on a max and a min. Then, if $A \subset B, d(A,B)>0$ , and the result is possible.

I think this should work: Assume A compact, contained in B. Then, for every $a \in A $, there is a ball $B(a,r) \subset B ; r>0$ . Cover the boundary of $B$ by these balls $B(a,r)$ and take a finite subcover. In this finite subcover, take  EDIT $Min r: B(a,r) \subset B $. This $r$ should give you the room to expand ino $B$ while still being contained in it.

Comment: don't you mean taking the minimal r?

Comment: @AvivEshed: Yes, sorry, let me edit.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $B = \{(x,y):\space y < 1/(1+x^2)\}$ and $A$ the $x$-axis.

EDIT: If $A$ is compact, the answer is yes.
Proof: For each point $x\in A$ put a closed ball that is inside $B$ to $x$. Since $A$ is compact it's covered with finitely many of these balls. Take the union of the balls as $A'$. To make sure you "inflate", cover the boundary of $A$ "thickly enough" (i.e make sure you don't have a place where two balls would be just tangent to each other).

This would need some argument to make it rigorous but hope you get the idea.

Comment: if A was compact, could my question be possible?

Comment: Yes, then it is true. There was an answer that gave a proof just by having also that $A$ is compact, but it was deleted (or no?). The idea was that the distance of the boundary of $A$ to B attains its minimum.

Comment: Interesting... I will try to find it

Comment: @AvivEshed I mean there was an answer to this question but it got deleted. I added (somewhat still unrigorous) proof for the compact case.